# Code Blocks throws expected primary-expression error about for_each

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, codeblocks

I am creating a game using Irrlicht and am currently making the Linux version. I moved my code over to Code:Blocks and have removed stuff like the pragmas, but I get the following errors about my for_each loops:

```
||=== Build: Debug in IrrlichtScene (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|115|error: expected primary-expression before ‘mod’|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|115|error: ‘for_each’ was not declared in this scope|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|159|error: expected primary-expression before ‘m’|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|165|error: expected primary-expression before ‘var’|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|171|error: expected primary-expression before ‘an’|
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/IRRPROJECT/TerrainStarter/terrain.cpp|231|warning: unused variable ‘movy’ [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is what my loops look like:

```
for_each (ModelLoader mod in models)
{
    mod.Load();
}
```

I understand that there may be a subtle difference in the code comparing to visual studio, but I never had any issues on my Visual Studio version. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The Visual Studio *extension* (which is useless with C++11) is `for each`.

Comment: @chris There is indeed a [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) in the `<algorithm>` library, it is not an extension. Though you are correct, range based for loops have all but replaced the need for this function.

Comment: how do install the extension or change to C++11, mine is currently on C++98 for some reason

Comment: @Oliver, It's a VS extension. It comes with that compiler and only that compiler. There's some compiler options page in CodeBlocks to switch standards.

Comment: @Cyber, MSVC actually has `for each (Type t in cont) {}`. MS recommends not using it if range-based for loops are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a range-based for loop instead of [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) here

```
for (auto& mod : models)
{
    mod.Load();
}
```

Otherwise if you want to stick with `for_each` you'd do

```
std::for_each(models.begin(), models.end(), [](ModelLoader& mod){ mod.Load(); });
```

Comment: it doesnt let me use the range-based loop because it says im using C++98, how do I change to C++11 and if I try running the finished program on an older pc could this cause issues?